# Matlab - Help in listing files using a name-pattern

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a function that lists the content of a folder based on a pattern, however the listing includes more files than needed. I'll explain by an example: Consider a folder containing the files

```
file.dat
file.dat._
file.dat.000
file.dat.001
...
file.dat.999
```

I am interested *only* in the files that are .000, .001 and so on. The files `file.dat` and `file.dat._` are to be excluded.
The later numbering can also be .0000,.0001 and so on, so number of digits is not necessarily 3.

I tried using the Dir command with the pattern `file.dat.*` - this included `file.dat` for some reason (Why the last comma treated differently?) and `file.dat._`, which was expected.

The "obvious" set of solutions is to add an additional regular expression or length check - however I would like to avoid that, if possible.
This needs to work both under UNIX and Windows (and preferably MacOS).

Any elegant solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Get all filenames with `dir` and filter them using with the regex `'^file\.dat\.\d+$'`. This matches:

- start of the string (`^`)
- followed by the string `file.dat.` (`file\.dat\.`)
- followed by one or more digits (`\d+`)
- and then the string must end (`$`)

Since the output of `dir` is a cell array of char vectors, `regex` returns a cell array with the matching indices of each char vector. The matching indices can only be `1` or `[]`, so `any` is applied to each cell's content to reduce it to `true` or `false` The resulting logical index tells which filenames should be kept.

```
f = dir('path/to/folder');
names = {f.name};
ind = cellfun(@any, regexp(names, '^file\.dat\.\d+$'));
names = names(ind);
```

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the OP prefers to avoid regex

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyway :)